# not understanding specific function

Tags: algorithm

I found code for solving Sudoku, but my problem is that I dont fully understand one function.

Here is code:

```
using System;

namespace Sudoku
{
class Program
{

    static char[][] LoadTable()
    {

        char[][] table = new char[9][];

        Console.WriteLine("Enter Sudoku table:");

        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            string line = Console.ReadLine();
            table[i] = line.PadRight(9).Substring(0, 9).ToCharArray();
            for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
                if (table[i][j] < '0' || table[i][j] > '9')
                    table[i][j] = '.';
        }

        return table;

    }

    static void PrintTable(char[][] table, int stepsCount)
    {
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Solved table after {0} steps:", stepsCount);
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", new string(table[i]));
    }

    static char[] GetCandidates(char[][] table, int row, int col)
    {

        string s = "";

        for (char c = '1'; c <= '9'; c++)
        {

            bool collision = false;

            for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
            {
                if (table[row][i] == c ||
                    table[i][col] == c ||
                    table[(row - row % 3) + i / 3][(col - col % 3) + i % 3] == c)
                {
                    collision = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!collision)
                s += c;

        }

        return s.ToCharArray();

    }

    static bool Solve(char[][] table, ref int stepsCount)
    {

        bool solved = false;

        int row = -1;
        int col = -1;
        char[] candidates = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
                if (table[i][j] == '.')
                {
                    char[] newCandidates = GetCandidates(table, i, j);
                    if (row < 0 || newCandidates.Length < candidates.Length)
                    {
                        row = i;
                        col = j;
                        candidates = newCandidates;
                    }
                }

        if (row < 0)
        {
            solved = true;
        }
        else
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < candidates.Length; i++)
            {
                table[row][col] = candidates[i];
                stepsCount++;
                if (Solve(table, ref stepsCount))
                {
                    solved = true;
                    break;
                }
                table[row][col] = '.';
            }
        }

        return solved;

    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        while (true)
        {

            char[][] table = LoadTable();
            int stepsCount = 0;
            if (Solve(table, ref stepsCount))
                PrintTable(table, stepsCount);
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Could not solve this Sudoku.");

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.Write("More? (y/n) ");
            if (Console.ReadLine().ToLower() != "y")
                break;

        }
    }
}
}
```

Program is supposed to find smallest array with possibly candidates and then test those candidates.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < candidates.Length; i++)
        {
            table[row][col] = candidates[i];
            stepsCount++;
            if (Solve(table, ref stepsCount))
            {
                solved = true;
                break;
            }
            table[row][col] = '.';
        }
```

But im not understanding why in this function immediately after IF is not true, table has value '.'. Wouldn't then cell always have a '.' because in this recursion we will get false value? How are those candidates filled in Sudoku?

Comment: There is a `break;` inside the `if` block, so the line `table[row][col] = '.';` is not always executed.

Answer (score 0):

The [`break;` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/break) causes the `for` loop to stop executing immediately, so the `table[row][col]` assignment gets skipped, and execution moved to the line of code after the end of the `for` loop.